# How to add pivot table when inserting data to database in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

maybe someone know how to insert pivot table in Laravel 8 automatically every i insert counselings table?

I have Model Counseling n to n Problem,

Input form
[image]

counselings table

[image]

problems table

[image]

Counselings Model

[image]

Problem Model

[image]

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.counseling.create', [
        'title' => 'Tambah Bimbingan dan Konseling',
        'students' => Student::all(),
        'problems' => Problem::all()
    ]);
}

public function find_nis(Request $request)
{
    $student = Student::with('student_class', 'counselings')->findOrFail($request->id);
    return response()->json($student);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{ dd($request->all());
    $counseling = new Counseling();
    $counseling->student_id = $request->student_id;
    $counseling->user_id = Auth::user()->id;     
    $counseling->save();

    if ($counseling->save()) {
        $problem = new Problem();
        $problem->id = $request->has('problem_id');
        $problem->save();
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: dont forget to add validation or somekind of extra check [amat penting = very important], especially on $request->problem_id , if not exists don't use attach() , instead throw error before create Counseling

Comment: hello @Win, thankyou for your response, ya thankyou I'll add the validation later. I'm currently focusing to build the main features first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your store() method to something like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $counseling = Counseling::create([
         'student_id' => $request->student_id,
         'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
    if($request->has('problem_id'){
         $counseling->problems()->attach($request->problem_id);
         //return something if problem id is in request
    }
    //return something if problem id is not there
}
```

Comment: Hello @StewieSWS thankyou for your response, but i dont want to insert data to problem  table, just want to insert the pivot table and the counseling table only. so how should i do?

Comment: I'll edit my answer then

Comment: @StewieSWS best to add validation into store() method to make sure $request->problem_id does exists , or when does not exist , create new Problem and attach id

Comment: thankyou @StewieSWS, you are my heroes :)

Answer (score 3):

You can insert into a pivot table in a few different ways. I would refer you to the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

1. Attaching

> You may use the attach method to attach a role to a user by inserting
> a record in the relationship's intermediate table:

Example:

```
$problem->counselings()->attach($counseling->id);
```

2. Sync

> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many
> associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the
> intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be
> removed from the intermediate table.

Example:

```
$problem->counselings()->sync($counselingsToSync);
```

3. Toggle

> The many-to-many relationship also provides a toggle method which
> "toggles" the attachment status of the given related model IDs. If the
> given ID is currently attached, it will be detached. Likewise, if it
> is currently detached, it will be attached:

Example:

```
$problem->counselings()->toggle($counselingsToToggle);
```